# uncaught error:java.net connectionexeption.failed to connect to "ip address"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm

Iam working on react native and using expo.After following all instructions I use expo (when i scan the code)but it shows following error *something went wrong could not load exp:"my ip address"*

**and this is in error log** :*uncaught error:java.net connectionexeption.failed to connect to "my ip address"*

Comment: Looks like somewhere you copied the string `"my ip address"` when you were instead supposed to replace it with the digits of your ip address. Was there some tutorial or setup guide you were following?

Comment: @NicholasToweri thought it is not safe to share ip address thats all.....I used  official react page as setup guide

Comment: @krishna can you show the code where you store your IP on " `my IP  address` " ?